# Outlook 2011 - clicking email addresses inside the application opening in Apple Mail

Tags: mail.app, ms-office

I use Apple Mail for my personal mail, and Outlook 2011 for work.  I have Mail as my default client, as when browsing the web / writing mail, I want to send all emails from that account.

However, I use Outlook for work.  When I need to send a new email to someone in outlook, say an email, and their name is blue and highlighted, I click their name. However, it opens a new mail message in Apple Mail instead of Outlook.

How can I have Outlook know that if I'm using Outlook, I want to send new messages FROM Outlook?  I hope the question is clear!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting Default mail Client tells your system to use that one when requesting email from other applications. (outside of Email).

While in Email (Outlook or Mail) they will do as told.

In your case using MS Office Word, Excel, PowerPoint with email link in one of the documents, will by default use the chosen default mail client.

There is a simple work around.
Since you are probably not using heavy duty MS Office applications to handle your Mail.app but do so with Outlook, I would make the Outlook the default mail application.
Now you can use Mail as email and Outlook will be the default mail client for your work.

Comment: I made Outlook my default and it seems that in Mail they open in Mail and in Outlook they open in Outlook, but from Firefox they go to Outlook, so it doesn't really make my work easier

Comment: Please clarify! what default email client do you like to have ????

Comment: I want Apple Mail to be my default client.  In Outlook, when I click an email address, I want it to open a new mail email in Outlook.  Hairofthedog in the other question said Outlook chose to make it look at default client first.

Comment: Thank you, so there is no problem then. Each mail client will do what you want (for example when you start new email in Outlook it will use Outlook for that) and so on. However any external links (external to the email it self) like in MS office or on any web sites will use the DEFAULT client- in your case Mail.app.

Comment: external email links in Outlook open in Apple Mail

Comment: and that is correct, ANY external link will do so, regardless of application it is in.

Comment: Yes, it does what it's designed to do, but it's incredibly unpractical since I have two mail clients.  If someone emails me in one, when I click the email address I'd expect it to open in Outlook, but it doesn't.  I think I might try to fix this loading mail in both clients, turning off all alerts for one of them, and that way when I click a link, if it opens in mail I can still respond without having to copy and paste the email address back into outlook

Comment: Sorry, we are limited on long discussions here, but I agree with you and hope that eventually the software writers will catch up with 21 century where people use more than single mail client. Please close this question as done :)

Answer (score 0):

I have had the opportunity to directly ask this question to the Mac Outlook team. The answer is that this is by design. When you click on a hyperlink Outlook doesn't first check to see what kind of link it is. Outlook asks OS X to decide how to open the hyperlink. If some email app other than Outlook is the current default email app then that's what will open the mailto: hyperlink.

Comment: That's too bad.  It's so annoying

Answer (score 0):

SImple solution. you need to set your default mail app.  Read here:

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201607